# 'while read line' assume enter key is pressed and only executes one iteration, but 'for line in blah' works approropriately

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I have a python script that I'm executing in the terminal. The python script does some things in the background, and then waits (using a raw_input) for an "enter" key to be pressed before continuing.

For simplicity sake, let's say the python script is the following:

```
import sys
print 'PRESS ENTER'
a = raw_input()
print 'you wrote %s' %sys.argv[1]
print 'done'
```

To execute this script over a number of different variables, I did the following:

```
macbookpro2:~$ echo '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9' |while read line; do python test.py $line; done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 1
done
```

It didn't iterate through all of the numbers, and the raw_input seemed to have been pressed for me without any action on my part...

In this other method, it expected my enter key for each one and executed appropriately:

macbookpro2:~$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do python test.py $i; done
    PRESS ENTER

```
you wrote 1
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 2
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 3
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 4
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 5
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 6
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 7
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 8
done
PRESS ENTER

you wrote 9
done
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this happened?

Comment: In linux bash, the version with `echo` works as you would expect, with one invocation per input line.  The mac terminal behavior is arguably a bug.

Comment: Hi @JuanTomas, I see the same behavior running ubuntu 14.04 and mac osx

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I had done a basic test using `echo` to make sure there was a separate invocation per line.  But with `python test.py $line` I get the same behavior as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` reads from standard input. In your test, that input is inherited from the loop from which the script is run, so it *also* reads from the `echo` statement, not the keyboard. Also, Python uses buffered input by default; even though `raw_input` only *returns* a single line of input, Python is reading the rest of the input to the loop into an internal buffer in case `raw_input` is called again. The next time `read` is called, there is nothing left to read.

You get a different result by turning off buffering with the `-u` option:

```
echo '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9' | while read line; do python -u tmp.py $line; done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 1
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 3
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 5
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 7
done
PRESS ENTER
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Now, `raw_input` is still reading from the same input "file" as `read`, but is guaranteed to read only the one line it will return. So the odd numbers are read by the `read` command, and the even numbers server as the "ENTER" prompted by the Python script. To see each number piped into the loop, provide Python with its own standard input:

```
echo '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9' | while read line; do echo | python -u tmp.py $line; done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 1
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 2
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 3
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 4
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 5
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 6
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 7
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 8
done
PRESS ENTER
you wrote 9
done
```